# How much space to allocate in an mpz_t (MPIR)?

Tags: c++, c, mpir

Supposing that I know how many digits my number might be (and I'd like to allocate the right amount of space the first time, how can I calculate the number of bytes I need to allocate? I suppose I could always set the value to be `1*10^(num digits)` and then `0` after but that feels wrong, and like I'm defeating the purpose.

Edit for clarity: I want to know how many bytes I need to store an integer with `n` decimal digits, and whether or not MPIRs implementation might affect that. @JonathonLeffler provided the correct answer in the comment to his answer.

Comment: Is this related to [GMP](http://gmplib.org/)?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The question is tagged MPIR, which apparently is a GMP fork (I had to look it up).

Comment: It's my belief that the best questions are free-standing.  Tags, and even titles, are auxilliary information.  A question should be answerable even if the tags and title are missing.

Answer (score 4):

Since there is an MPIR tag, this is probably about [MPIR](http://mpir.org/), a fork of GMP.  And in the current documentation (PDF only — no online HTML), under the heading 'Initializing integers', you can find:

> `void mpz_init2(mpz_t integer, mp_bitcnt_t n)`
>
> Initialize
>   `integer`, with space for
>   `n` bits, and set its value to 0.
>   `n`
>   is only the initial space,
>   `integer`
>   will grow automatically in the normal way, if necessary,
>   for subsequent values stored.
>   `mpz_init2`
>   makes it possible to avoid such reallocations if a
>   maximum size is known in advance.

If this was for [GMP](http://gmplib.org/), you can read the online manual on [Initializing integers](https://gmplib.org/manual/Initializing-Integers.html#Initializing-Integers) to find:

> — Function: `void mpz_init2(mpz_t x, mp_bitcnt_t n)`
>
> Initialize `x`, with space for `n`-bit numbers, and set its value to 0. Calling this function instead of `mpz_init` or `mpz_inits` is never necessary; reallocation is handled automatically by GMP when needed.
>
> While `n` defines the initial space, `x` will grow automatically in the normal way, if necessary, for subsequent values stored. `mpz_init2` makes it possible to avoid such reallocations if a maximum size is known in advance.
>
> In preparation for an operation, GMP often allocates one limb more than ultimately needed. To make sure GMP will not perform reallocation for `x`, you need to add the number of bits in mp_limb_t to `n`.

The two are essentially the same.

Comment: Yes, I read this documentation. My question, I suppose, is more about how I calculate the number of maximum bits I need based on the maximum number of digits I am allowed. It's not the end of the world though, a minor optimization.

Comment: If you know the number of decimal digits, then the number of bits needed is approximately log2(10) * decimal_digits, isn't it?  It helps you get the right answer if you ask the question clearly — and include background information on what you know and what you want explained.

Comment: That is what I was looking for, just a bit unsure about whether MPIRs implementation might have an effect. No one intentionally asks a question badly.